# Webpack 2 regex test failing

Tags: javascript, regex, webpack, css-modules

I cant quite get my head around why my loader tests are failing.

My goal:

**Test 1:**

Match anything that is **not** either `global.css` or `global.scss`

**Test 2**

**Only** match either `global.scss` or `global.css`

---

Reason being is i don't want any files named global to be passed through the `module` options

Seems like my first test is letting global though. I can see both my regex are correctly returning true/false when using tools such as https://regex101.com/.

Could this be down to my `include`?

Help! :)

**webpack.config.js**

```
        {

            test: /^(?!global\.s?css$).*\.s?css$/,
            include: SRC_DIR,
            use: extractPlugin.extract({
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            modules: true,
                            camelCase: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: { 
                            plugins: (loader) => [require('autoprefixer')()]
                        }
                    },
                    'resolve-url-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: { sourceMap: true }
                    }
                ]
            })
        },

        {

            test: /^global\.s?css$/,
            include: SRC_DIR,
            use: extractPlugin.extract({
                use: [
                    'css-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: { 
                            plugins: (loader) => [require('autoprefixer')()]
                        }
                    },
                    'resolve-url-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: { sourceMap: true }
                    }
                ]
            })
        }
```

Comment: tests expect to match the whole file path, like 'path/to/global.scss', not only 'global.scss'.

Comment: if thats the case then why does `test: /\.(css|scss)$/` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Test 2 try dropping the `^` from your regex. The tests are matched against the file path, not just the file name, so having it start from the beginning of the path will cause it to fail.

For Test 1 you could simplify this negative pattern by using `test: \/.s?css$\` to capture all styles and then add `exclude: \global.s?css$\` to prevent global from being included.